# cvs check out warning, "cvs checkout: Skipping `$Log$' keyword due to excessive comment leader."

Tags: cvs

when i checked out my code from cvs, i met this error/warning

```
"cvs checkout: Skipping `$Log$' keyword due to excessive comment leader."
```

how to fix it? or is there any materials regarding this error?

Comment: To those voting to close version control questions are on topic for SO